# QUnit - how to compare two complex objects

Tags: javascript, qunit

I am unit testing some serialisation and deserialisation logic in a fairly complex JavaScript application, using QUnit, but I'm having trouble getting my tests to pass.

The two checks that look as though they should do the right thing are [deepEqual](http://api.qunitjs.com/deepEqual/) or [propEqual](http://api.qunitjs.com/propEqual/), however, neither appears to do exactly what I want:

If I use `deepEqual` and the two objects do not match, the assertion fails and it shows me a diff indicating the problems. However if there is no difference I just get a failure message showing the first parameter handed to the equality check as the "Expected" value without the second parameter or any indication of what the difference is. I think this is possibly because they aren't the same object, but I'm not sure.

If I use `propEqual` I just get a message saying `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded     at String.match (native)` and the test fails.

Is it possible to perform this type of check with QUnit? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the test code, and possibly the objects your comparing (or maybe just part of them)?

Comment: Just as a side note, `deepEqual` does not require the objects to be the same item in memory, it digs down into the object to compare individual properties.

Comment: @jakarella, honestly I can't share the detail as you'd need about two thirds of my application to be able to see everything that is being serialised and deserialised and the test is just `var a=new myType(); var b=a.serialise(); var c=b.deserialise(); deepEqual(a, c);`

Comment: Hmm... So, without knowing anything else, it's hard to say what's wrong. In my experience though, comparing large objects is treacherous in any framework. I usually try to compare multiple smaller objects instead. In your use case though, not sure that makes sense. Sorry I can't be of more help here.

Comment: @jakarella, I appreciate it. I think probably I will end up doing it manually with the things I know about the system but QUnit can't, but I didn't want to invent unnecessary wheels.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into the second problem with `propEqual` I describe above, the problem causing me trouble was a circular reference where a child object held a reference to it's parent, which was then sending QUnit into a spin. It is possible to adjust the `objectValues` function so that it marks objects as "seen" when it has already processed them and only processes unseen objects. With this in place the comparison works for me.